# Calculating a column in SQL using the column's own output as input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have problem that I find very hard to solve:

I need to calculate a column R_t in SQL where for each row, the sum of the "previous" calculated values SUM(R_t-1) is required as input. The calculation is done grouped over a ProjectID column. I have no clue how to proceed.

The formula for the calculation I am trying to achieve is R_t = ([Contract value]*t - SUM(R*{t-1})) / [Remaining Hours]_t * [HoursRegistered]*t where "t" denotes time and SUM(R*{t-1}) is the sum of R_t from t = 0 to t-1.

Time is always consecutive and always begin in t = 0. But number of time periods may differ across [ProjectID], i.e. one project having t = {0,1,2} and another t = {0,1,2,3,4,5}. The time period will never "jump" from 5 to 7

The expected output (using the data from below is) for ProjectID 101 is

```
R_0 = (500,000 - 0) / 500 * 65 = 65,000
R_1 = (500,000 - (65,000)) / 435 * 100 = 100,000
R_2 = (500,000 - (65,000 + 100,000)) / 335 * 85 = 85,000
R_3 = (500,000 - (65,000 + 100,000 + 85,000)) / 250 * 69 = 69,000
```

etc...

This calculation is done for each ProjectID.

My question is how to formulate this in a SQL query? My first thought was to create a recursive CTE, but I am actually not sure it is the right way proceed. Recursive CTE is (from my understanding) made for handling more of hierarchical like structure, which this isn't really.

My other thought was to calculate the SUM(R_t-1) using windowed functions, ie SUM OVER (PARITION BY ORDER BY) with a LAG, but the recursiveness really gives me trouble and I run my head against the wall when I am trying.

Below a query for creating the input data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InputForRecursiveCalculation]
(
     [Time] int NULL,
     ProjectID [int],
     ContractValue float,
     ContractHours float,
     HoursRegistered float,
     RemainingHours float
) 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[InputForRecursiveCalculation]
(
  [Time]
 ,[ProjectID]
 ,[ContractValue]
 ,[ContractHours]
 ,[HoursRegistered]
 ,[RemainingHours]
)
VALUES
 (0,101,500000,500,65,500), 
 (1,101,500000,500,100,435),    
 (2,101,500000,500,85,335),
 (3,101,500000,500,69,250),
 (4,101,450000,650,100,331),    
 (5,101,450000,650,80,231),
 (6,101,450000,650,90,151),
 (7,101,450000,650,45,61),
 (8,101,450000,650,16,16),
 (0,110,120000,90,10,90),   
 (1,110,120000,90,10,80),   
 (2,110,130000,90,10,70),   
 (3,110,130000,90,10,60),   
 (4,110,130000,90,10,50),   
 (5,110,130000,90,10,40),   
 (6,110,130000,90,10,30),   
 (7,110,130000,90,10,20),   
 (8,110,130000,90,10,10)

GO
```

For those of you who dare downloading something from a complete stranger, I have created an Excel file demonstrating the calculation (please download the file as you will not be to see the actual formula in the HTML representation shown when first clicking the link):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rxz72lbvooyc4y/Calculation%20example.xlsx?dl=0

Best regards,
Victor

Comment: You're unlikely to find people are going to download your Excel file. if you want to show expected results, put them in your question.

Comment: Please explain the logic. The Excel shows values at least I don't understand... You might read about `SUM()` with an `OVER()`  clause (windowing functions) and about `LAG()` and `LEAD()`

Comment: Hi both of you, thank you for your replies. I will explain the logic in the question instead

Comment: Sounds like something for a temporary table or two. Or local variables. Or both.

Comment: Just realised your equation is `current = (ContractValue - (previous)) / RemainingHours * HoursRegistered`. You also mention grouping by ID; is that project ID?  In terms of determining current and previous, is that based on Time?

Comment: Also, is Time always consecutive; i.e. could it ever skip from 5 to 7 for a given project?

Comment: You still haven't explained anything.  I posted an answer based on what I think you are trying to do.  But I could be wrong.  Don't blame me, you gave little information.

Comment: Could RemainingHours ever be 0?  What should happen in that instance (i.e. as we then have a divide by zero scenario)

Comment: Add your expected output to the question.

Comment: I am sorry if I am not being clear enough. Working on updating my question. Time is always consecutive and always begin in t = 0. But number of time periods may differ across [ProjectID], i.e. one project having t = {0,1,2} and another t = {0,1,2,3,4,5}. The time period will never "jump" from 5 to 7.

Comment: I will add the expected output to the question. One moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be usefull for you. There is additional column SumR that stands for sumarry of previest rows (for ProjectID)

```
;with recu as
(
    select
        Time,
        ProjectId,
        ContractValue,
        ContractHours,
        HoursRegistered,
        RemainingHours,
        cast((ContractValue - 0)*HoursRegistered/RemainingHours as numeric(15,0)) as R,
        cast((ContractValue - 0)*HoursRegistered/RemainingHours as numeric(15,0)) as SumR
    from
        InputForRecursiveCalculation
    where
        Time=0

    union all

    select
        input.Time,
        input.ProjectId,
        input.ContractValue,
        input.ContractHours,
        input.HoursRegistered,
        input.RemainingHours,
        cast((input.ContractValue - prev.SumR)*input.HoursRegistered/input.RemainingHours as numeric(15,0)),
        cast((input.ContractValue - prev.SumR)*input.HoursRegistered/input.RemainingHours + prev.SumR  as numeric(15,0))

    from
        recu prev
        inner join
        InputForRecursiveCalculation input
            on input.ProjectId = prev.ProjectId
            and input.Time = prev.Time + 1
)
select
    *
from
    recu
order by
    ProjectID,
    Time
```

RESULTS:

```
Time        ProjectId   ContractValue          ContractHours          HoursRegistered        RemainingHours         R                                       SumR
----------- ----------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
0           101         500000                 500                    65                     500                    65000                                   65000
1           101         500000                 500                    100                    435                    100000                                  165000
2           101         500000                 500                    85                     335                    85000                                   250000
3           101         500000                 500                    69                     250                    69000                                   319000
4           101         450000                 650                    100                    331                    39577                                   358577
5           101         450000                 650                    80                     231                    31662                                   390239
6           101         450000                 650                    90                     151                    35619                                   425858
7           101         450000                 650                    45                     61                     17810                                   443668
8           101         450000                 650                    16                     16                     6332                                    450000
0           110         120000                 90                     10                     90                     13333                                   13333
1           110         120000                 90                     10                     80                     13333                                   26666
2           110         130000                 90                     10                     70                     14762                                   41428
3           110         130000                 90                     10                     60                     14762                                   56190
4           110         130000                 90                     10                     50                     14762                                   70952
5           110         130000                 90                     10                     40                     14762                                   85714
6           110         130000                 90                     10                     30                     14762                                   100476
7           110         130000                 90                     10                     20                     14762                                   115238
8           110         130000                 90                     10                     10                     14762                                   130000
```